# How to use data mining feature of SQL Server 2008 with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-mining, ssas

How to use data mining feature of SQL Server 2008 with ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SqlServerDataMining.com](http://www.sqlserverdatamining.com/ssdm/), a site run by Microsoft's SQL Server Data Mining team.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you want to:

- Build cubes to model your data
- Build a prediction calculator (or whatever kind of calculator you're looking to use)
- Expose that via a web service
- Call the web service in your app

For example, if you want to model whether or not a customer is likely to abandon their shopping card, you would figure out what characteristics of a shopper you want to capture and analyze.  You set up your cubes to model what characteristics are indicative of a soon-to-be-bailing-out shopper.  During the shopping process, your web app would send the shopper's characteristics to the SSAS server, which would return back a guess about whether or not the shopper is going to abandon the cart.  Then your web app can take proactive measures before they leave.

All of the steps in here are kinda complicated - your best bet is probably to refine your question to focus on the areas you're responsible for.